# How to migrate from JRE 1.6 to JDK 1.6?

Tags: macos, java, homebrew

My Mac `Mountain Lion` came with `JRE 1.6`.  However, I would like to have the full JDK.  I read somewhere that for that on Mac it is better to consult Apple rather than Oracle for downloads/install packages but Apple doesn't seem to offer much support for Java 6 (which I need to work on, can't upgrade to 7).  Better yet, if such an upgrade is available through `homebrew`.

Comment: If you have Java enabled in your browser, I recommend that you switch to Java 1.7.  Java 1.6 is no longer supported by Oracle: it has been end-of-lifed and Oracle is no longer providing security patches for Java 1.6.  Java 1.6 is under active attack and there are exploits in the wild.  It might not be the best idea in the world to have Java 1.6 enabled in your browser while browsing.  The only version of Java 1.6 that is currently believed to be safe in your browser, as far as I can tell, is 6u51.

Answer (score 1):

Java JRE and JDKS 1.6 and lower are supplied from Apple and 1.7 or 8 are from Oracle.

The latest Apple one is [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) I think.
This installs the JDK and the JRE.

the JDK is under `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/` but /usr/bin contains java, javac etc so will be on the path